# Why would the `plot` method of the `matplotlib` library return an empty list?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was hoping to make two different plots using `matplotlib`.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as pltlib
import numpy as np

x1 = np.arange(1, 5, 0.1)
y1 = np.sin(x1)

x2 = np.arange(1, 5, 0.1)
y2 = np.log10(x2)

plot1 = pltlib.plot()

plot2 = pltlib.plot(x2, y2)

print(type(plot1))
print(plot1)

# print(type(plot2))
# print(plot2)
```

Why does the [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)  method return an empty list when a person tries to plot nothing at all? If there is no input data, shouldn't an exception be raised?

Comment: This isn't really an answerable question since it boils down to whatever the developers decided. As a side note, you should write the import by convention as `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Comment: This is pretty standard and what I would expect. None of these raises: `list(), str(), int()`. I feel like an empty plot is the matplotlib equivalent of zero or an empty string

Comment: As no points are provided so the library is returning empty list .

Answer (score 2):

The plot method returns a list of lines representing the plotted data. Because there are no lines representing the plotted data that's why it's returning an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

The `plot` function supports multiple plots. For example, the following call is reasonable:

```
plt.plot(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
```

In programming and mathematics, when any number of things is acceptable, a special case of 0 things is useful. So, if I developed a library which plotted things, and it could plot several things at once, I would support plotting an empty list of things without error.

If the number of plots in your script is variable, you don't have to bypass the `plot` call when the list is empty.

```
data = []
while ...:
    if ...:
        data.append(x)
        data.append(y)
plot(*data)
```